# Google error-prone, how to limit access to other packages or modules

Tags: java, errorprone

Our module, a maven module named **Z** depends on **A**.

**A** depends on **B** which depends on **C**, **D**

Is there a way to limit in our module **Z** access only to code/packages directly available in **A**, so that a build will fail only if **Z**  accesses **B**, **C** or **D** ?

Module/jar **B** should still be able to access **C, D**.

How is this done in error-prone?

**Examples** **valued** as documentation on error-prone is lacking.

Other questions regarding error-prone of interest:

1. How can I limit access from another package for another package?
2. Is it possible to limit access of a class to another set of packages, modules?
3. What versions of Java does error-prone currently work with?
4. Are there any books, documents on error-prone?

**Examples valued.**

Comment: Would `@RestrictedApi` do what you need? http://errorprone.info/api/latest/com/google/errorprone/annotations/RestrictedApi.html

Comment: @AndyTurner Partly one of the questions perhaps. However, it would require modifying existing source. How about limiting access to parts of a third party dependency (and their  sub dependencies?)